# Logstash Http output filter

Tags: filter, logstash

How can I customize the http output filter to retrieve a JWT token (using client id and secret) and then use it to post the log entries to a REST API ?

Answer (score 0):

The [http output plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-http.html) does not support this per default, however you can try to implement using a `translate` filter to add a field with an external value, which would be your token, and the [headers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-http.html) option of the http output plugin.

First you would need to create a file with your token in the following format.

```
"jwttoken": "your-jwt-token"
```

Then you need to use `mutate` to add a new field the will be used in the `translate` filter.

```
mutate {
    add_field => { "webtoken" => "jwttoken" }
}
```

This will add the field `webtoken` with the value `jwttoken`.

Now you can use the `translate` filter to replace the value `jwttoken` with your token.

```
translate {
    dictionary_path => '/path/to/the/file/with/token.yml'
    field => 'webtoken'
    destination => 'webtoken'
    override => true
    refresh_interval => 1800
}
```

This filter will read the value of the field `webtoken`, look into the dictionary for a line with the same value, in this case `jwttoken`, and if found it will replace this value with the value from the dictionary file, it will also re-read the file again every 1800 seconds, which can be changed according to the expiration time of your token.

After this filter the field `webtoken` will have the value `your-jwt-token`.

Now create a field with the string for the authorization.

```
mutate {
    add_field => { "authtoken" => "Basic %{webtoken}" }
}
```

To use this token in your `http` output you need to add a custom header.

```
http {
    headers => [
        "Authorization", "%{authtoken}"
    ]
}
```

You will also need to implement a way to update your dictionary file, but a simple python or bash script can solve this problem.